# How to access the location and value of changed cell in BindingDataChanged event in officeJS?

Tags: excel, office-js

On `BindingSelectionChanged` - `eventArgs` provides the following -

```
eventArgs.startRow;
eventArgs.rowCount;
eventArgs.startColumn;
eventArgs.columnCount;
```

On `BindingDataChanged` - event args does not provide the above 4 params. Please advise if there is any specific way to get those.

My intention is to be able to display the old value of the cells that have been changed in a matrix binding.

Answer (score 0):

This data isn't provided in the arguments. You would need to store the current state using [getDataAsync()](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/binding.getdataasync) and upon receiving `BindingDataChanged` event re-pull the data to compare them.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. I'm trying to retrieve the location of the changed cell in my BindingDataChanged handler. The eventArgs object doesn't provide any information for me to detect which cell was changed.

Comment: getDataAsync() returns the entire matrix. Comparing it element by element with the old data will require a lot of computations. I wanted to know if there is any way I can just access the location of the single cell that was changed.

Comment: Correct, it doesn't return the location. It returns the "binding" that was changed. This could be a single cell, a matrix of cells or a table. There isn't a method for obtaining which sell was changed. You could however track the current "selection". If you get a `BindingDataChanged` event before a selection change, I believe that will get you what you're looking for.